# How to test if a Servlet Filter was called

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing, servlet-filters

We have a RESTful web service within an embedded Jetty running and I want to write an integration test that confirms that a special Servlet Filter has been called - because this depends of the correct requested URL. In this Servlet Filter a crucial session attribute is set which is important for the procedure that follows. How can I write such an integration test?

Comment: Alternatively you can test whether the crucial session attribute was added to you request and/or response, that way you know whether Servlet Filter was called or not.

Comment: @Elgayed: From outside (as a client when you call the RESTful resource) you don't get e.g. a HttpServletResponse object so to look into the session and check it.

Comment: Given a known value of the session attribute and how that value controls the important procedure, verify the results of the important procedure.

Comment: @AndrewS: You're right Andrew, instead checking any tiny details, like testing the session attribute, the test should be focused on the implicit outcome. I was also thinking about that.